# What does Islam say about drawing images of prophet Isha?

Tags: prophet-isa

I am a revert muslim, Islam is my religeon now and it is the religion of God. I want to say that Prophet Muhammed is my prophet, I respect and love him, a lot drawing pictures of propet Muhammad is idolatry, and prophet did not allow it so we can worship only one God, your Lord and my Lord forever. Drawing pictures of prophet Muhammed makes us angry. There are so many pictures of prophet Isha in this world, shouldn’t that make us angry because in islam drawing any prophet is not allowed, give me clarification on drawing images of prophet Isha so I can understand better. Do the muslim brothers my brothers know how prophet Isha looks like?

Answer (score -1):

Here is your answer in regard with images of prophet Jesus.

In my opinion, do not care about others of what they do, because the **Age of Prophets** is closed and only at that time you could get angry, but now it is another new age which is **Age of Modern Technology**

> 21:52-54 "When he said unto his father and his folk: What are these images unto which ye pay devotion? They said: We found our fathers worshippers of them. He said: Verily ye and your fathers were in plain error."

And do not get angry because God Says:

> God’s Messenger (ﷺ) said: Whoever makes a picture will be punished by God till he puts life in it, and he will never be able to put life in it.

And do not get angry because God will Take every individual into account, every deed and He is the most just. And He will deal with those who worship others instead Him. Because God Says:

> ”Surely whoever associates (others) with God, then God has forbidden to him the garden, and his abode is the fire; and there shall be no helpers for the unjust.” (Surah al-Mā’ida 5:72)

I think it is better if you don’t care about others

> I don’t need fighting. It’s the cherry on top To this beautiful life I’ve been given.
>      By Dominick Cruz

**Conclusion:** Do not get angry about others, if they do, they’ll get punished by God and you have to do what God orders you to do which is, to be kind, to love your parents, to perform daily obligatory prayers and believe in Him and all His prophets and angels and Jinns and leave this up to Him, He will take care of them on the day of judgement. And plus, life is full of beautiful surprises and you don’t have time to get angry, and it is better not to get angry because maybe you will have bad thoughts.

I hope that now it is correct answer.